# Negative binomial distribution and negative binomial series missing $(-1)^k$ term

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

The pmf of a negative binomial distribution is

$$p_X(x)= {x-1 \choose r-1}~ p^r~ (1-p)^{x-r}\quad x=r,r+1,\cdots$$

I want to verify that

$$\sum \limits_{x=r}^{\infty} p_X(x)= 1$$

I start with

$$\sum \limits_{x=r}^{\infty}  {x-1 \choose r-1}~ p^r~ (1-p)^{x-r}$$

Now let $k=x-r\Rightarrow x=k+r$

$$
p^r ~\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  {k+r-1 \choose r-1}~ (1-p)^{k+r-r}=
p^r ~\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  {k+r-1 \choose r-1}~ (1-p)^{k}
$$

At this point, the teacher is claiming that

$$
(1- p)^{-r}= \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  {k+r-1 \choose r-1}~ (1-p)^{k}
$$

is a negative binomial series.

However, when I look up negative binomial serial on Wolfram, I see that it has a $(-1)^k$ term in the summation.

---

- The **Negative Binomial Series**, arises from binomial theorem for negative integer, $-n$.
- ${-n \choose k}=(-1)^k~{n+k-1 \choose k}~~~\text{where } n>0,~ k>0$
- $(a+b)^{-n} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}~ {-n \choose k}~a^k~b^{-(n+k)}$

  where $|a| < b$
- $(a+b)^{-n} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k~{n+k-1\choose k}a^k~ b^{-(n+k)}$

  where $|a| < b$
- for $b=1$

  $(a+1)^{-n} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {-n \choose k}~a^k$

  $\boxed{(a+1)^{-n} =\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k~{n+k-1\choose k}~a^k}$

  $(a+1)^{-n} = 1 - na + \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)a^2 - \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(n+2)a^3+\cdots$

---

But, anyways returning the teacher's instruction.  At this point he says that the negative binomial series formula is

$$(1-y)^{-r}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {k+r-1 \choose r-1}y^r$$

Therefore, our equation becomes

$$
p^r(1-(1-p))^{-r}=p^r(p)^{-r}=1
$$

---

**Now for my question:**

What happened to the $(-1)^k$ term in the negative binomial series?  Is there a mistaken in the math somewhere where it should have a  $(-1)^k$?

Comment: Here's where the lesson comes from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-mLELmZdbQ and here's wolfram's page of negative binomial series. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html

Comment: I'm assuming after you say "At this point he says, negative binomial series formula is:" you meant $y^k$ instead of $y^r$?

Answer (score 1):

Taking your boxed equation $$(a+1)^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \binom{n+k-1}{k} a^k$$ and choosing $a = p-1$, $n = r$, we obtain $$p^{-n} = (1 + (p-1))^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \binom{k+r-1}{k} (p-1)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (-1)^k \binom{k+r-1}{r-1} (1-p)^k,$$ since $$\binom{k+r-1}{r-1} = \frac{(k+r-1)!}{k! (r-1)!} = \binom{k+r-1}{k},$$ and since the product $(-1)^k (-1)^k = ((-1)^2)^k = 1$, the result follows.

Comment: I don’t understand where the second $(-1)^k$ Came from, it looks like you pulled it out of thin air...

Comment: I think I get it,,,

Comment: @pico The second one came from flipping $(p-1)^k$ into $(1-p)^k$.

Answer (score 1):

To equate your professor's formula with Wolfram Alpha's formula for a negative binomial series, plug $-y$ in for $a$ and $r$ for $n$. After that, the trick to get rid of the $(-1)^k$ can be seen in heropup's answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a+1)^{-n} =\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k~{n+k-1\choose k}~a^k$$

Now let a=-b where b >0

$$(-b +1)^{-n} =\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k~{n+k-1\choose k}~(-b)^k$$

$$(1-b)^{-n} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (-1)^k~{n+k-1\choose k}~(b)^k$$

$$(1-b)^{-n} = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {n+k-1\choose k}~(b)^k$$